Looking for BBC(?) Children's Series about Modern Pentathlon
Late 1980s, possibly 1990, BBC (most likely) Children's TV series about a group of schoolchildren who end up taking part in a modern pentathlon competition. At least I remember the competition involving show jumping, archery so I'm assuming it is pentathlon.
Vague memories of the programme, but one scene involved one of the children on a horse, standing on a teacher's garden "blackmailing" them because of something that happened in school.
Likely to have been shown on weekends sometime during the late 1980s. Can't find the correct keywords to make a match on IMDB.

Archery isn't part of modern pentathlon. It's running, horseback riding, shooting (with a pistol), fencing, and swimming - all things that an officer in the military needs to be capable of. If you definitely remember archery, you probably need to rethink your search terms.

well, it might not have been (and probably wasn't) pentathlon - certainly some multi-event sports which included show jumping. So, some more details if it helps anyone: at least one girl with a horse, a teacher and at least one boy who had problems at home, and of course the whole sports event "saves" him...I was thinking this might have been made by CITV but I can't find either in Wikipedia's lists of 1980s children's programmes...anyway, to keep looking :-)

The series is "Who Sir Me Sir"  BBC, Broadcast 1985 http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0329944/

The series if "Who Sir? Me Sir?"  BBC, broadcast 1985
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0329944/

Well, this was an answer to my original question by myself so with that context.
